# How to implement high performance tree view in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, tree

What is the best way to build the table that will represent the tree?
I want to implement a select ,insert ,update and delete that will work well with big data.
The select for example will have to support "Expand ALL" - getting all the children (and there children) for a given node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `CTE`'s.

Given the tree-like table structure:

```
id parent name
1  0      Electronics
2  1      TV
3  1      Hi-Fi
4  2      LCD
5  2      Plasma
6  3      Amplifiers
7  3      Speakers
```

, this query will return `id`, `parent` and depth level, ordered as a tree:

```
WITH    v (id, parent, level) AS
        (
        SELECT  id, parent, 1
        FROM    table
        WHERE   parent = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, parent, v.level + 1
        FROM    v
        JOIN    table t
        ON      t.parent = v.id
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    v

id parent name
1  0      Electronics
2  1        TV
4  2          LCD
5  2          Plasma
3  1        Hi-Fi
6  3          Amplifiers
7  3          Speakers
```

Replace `parent = 0` with `parent = @parent` to get only a branch of a tree.

Provided there's an index on `table (parent)`, this query will efficiently work on a very large table, since it will recursively use  `INDEX LOOKUP` to find all chilrden for each parent.

To update a certain branch, issue:

```
WITH    v (id, parent, level) AS
        (
        SELECT  id, parent, 1
        FROM    table
        WHERE   parent = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, parent, v.level + 1
        FROM    v
        JOIN    table t
        ON      t.parent = v.id
        )
UPDATE  table t
SET     column = newvalue
WHERE   t.id IN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    v
        )
```

where `@parent` is the root of the branch.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the tables structure?
will this query work well with a large db?

Comment: thanks,
How can do a deep update? - update all the nodes under a parent? (including grandchildren)

Comment: hey, I'm trying to get this to work, and it looks like the vq item dosent work, I am trying in 2008 though. Also does level have to be stored in the database, as it's not shown in the table?

Comment: `@optician`: try now. `Level` is a pseudocolumn, it is generated and computed in the `CTE`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to ask yourself these questions first :
1) What is ratio of modifications vs reads ? (= mostly static tree or changing constantly?)
2) How deep and how large do you expect the tree to grow ?

Nested sets are great for mostly-static trees where you need operations on whole branches. It handles deep trees without problems.

Materialized path works well for dynamic (changing) trees with constrained/predictable depth.

Recursive CTEs are ideal for very small trees, but the branch operations ("get all children in this branch..") get very costly with deep / large tree.

Comment: My Tree is very dynamic, many updates but many selects as well.
And I'd like to be able to get deep as 10-15 levels.

I found this article about Nested sets:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/swinging-from-tree-to-tree-using-ctes-part-1-adjacency-to-nested-sets.aspx

Will Nested sets like described in this article be my best option?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Joe Celko's book on trees and hierarchies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202) for multiple ways to tackle the hierarchy problem. The model that you choose will depend on how you weight lookups vs. updates vs. complexity. You can make the lookups pretty fast (especially for getting all children in a node) using the adjacency list model, but updates to the tree are slower.

Comment: Thanks i'll look it up.
Is union all more efficient then the recursive?
I'v heard that mssql 2005 has a new way of dealing with trees, do you know if it works well with large DBs?

Comment: The UNION ALL within a CTE is recursive, although I'm not sure how SQL Server handles it behind the scenes or if there are performance tweaks to it. I haven't done enough large-scale testing with CTEs to say for sure about performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many updates and selects, the best option seems to be the Path Enumeration Model, which is briefly described here:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned going with a [Closure Table](https://coderwall.com/p/lixing). Very efficient for reads and pretty simple to write.